# FindBugs Null passed for non-null parameter of new java.math.BigInteger

Tags: java, findbugs

In the bellow snippet why does FindBugs complain about `null` being passed to a `BigInteger` constructor? It's says its known `null` at line:  `signature=null;`

```
byte[] signature;
Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar(
                        now.get(Calendar.YEAR), now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DATE),
                        now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), now.get(Calendar.SECOND));
Date d=today.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
String timestamp =sdf.format(d).toString();
String pp=user.userName+secretKeyStr+timestamp;
try {
    signature = Security.getMD5Hash(pp);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    signature=null;
}
//convert byte[] into String. method to generate MD5 hash of a string in Java
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1,signature);
```

is it a false positive ot am I missing something here?
should I return `null` on `Exception`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is known that `signature` **can** be null at the `new BigInteger(1,signature);` line. That is probably a bug because the constructor of `BigInteger` will throw a `NullPointerException` if one of the parameters is null.

You should handle your exception in some other way, for example by returning null (as you say). In my opinion, you should also catch a more specific exception than `Exception`.